# Como puedo mover el seek a la siguiente linea?

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente código

```
 lineas = 'CODIGO'+'\t'+'nombre'+'\t'+'apellido'+'\t'+'sueldo'+'\t';
 i = 0
 generate_cod = 0
 filename = './INFORMACION.TXT'
 with open(filename, "a+") as f:
      data = f.read()
      f.seek(0)
      f.write(lineas + '\n')
      f.truncate()
      f.close
```

Esto te escribe la linea que desees pero no se como pasar el cursor hacia la siguiente linea, ya que lo estoy haciendo con seek.

Ejemplo de lo que quiero escribir, alrededor de 100 campos

```
cod-empleado nombre apellido sueldo
  cod-001     Mario  Garcia   1200
```

Comment: Hola, ¿qué tipo de objeto es `lineas`? y ¿No es posible utilizar un bucle for?

Comment: Si haces `f.readline()`, te devuelve la línea actual (hasta que encuentre el próximo retorno de carro) y te deja el cursor al inicio de la línea siguiente. Entiendo que puedes hacer `f.readline()` y simplemente descartar la cadena que te retorne.

Comment: Ah, y a `f.close` le faltan los paréntesis para que sea una llamada: `f.close()`

Comment: Gracias, pero no entiendo muy bien, ¿si uso readline el cursor empezara en la siguiente linea?, eso suena genial

Comment: y de hecho @abulafia el f.close() no es necesario porque se está trabajando dentro de un `with` statement, que ya lo hace solo

Comment: Perdón, había entendido mal. Creía que querías "saltarte la primera línea" a la hora de escribir, para dejarla como estaba, y luego reemplazar las demás. Pero mirando mejor parece que quieres reemplazar _todas_ las líneas del fichero original. En ese caso ¿por qué lo estás abriendo en modo "append"? ¿Por qué no lo abres en modo "write", que borrará automáticamente el contenido antes de escribir nada?

Comment: @abulafia Yo entiendo que quiere, o bien escribir la información del archivo `f` en _otro lugar_ , o bien escribir la información de _otro lugar_ en el archivo `f` . Pero no sé cuál ese "otro lugar". Además también hay que saber **en qué formato** aparece originalmente. Además hay 2 variables `i = 0` `generate_cod = 0` que no sé muy bien qué hacen. Me parece bastante críptico.

Comment: lo que estoy buscando es escribir en la siguiente linea como '\n' pero con seek , no me he explicado bien así que perdón por eso.